# Why does my static php code disappear when i show wordpress post on front page?

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

On my frontpage i have a news module that basicly just shows the 5 newest posts from a news category. this is hardcoded into the design likeso:

```
    <h2>Nyheder</h2>
                <?php query_posts('category_name=nyheder&posts_per_page=5'); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
                    <a href="<?php the_field('link'); ?>"><?php the_time('M j, Y'); ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php the_title(); ?><br /><br /></a>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

for some reason when i press one of the news links in this section on my frontpage it displays the news post on my frontpages design but it removes the code that displays the other news topics on the sidebar.

the entire site and problem can be wieved here http://www.acagenturs.dk - Below the jquery banner there is 2 sections. 1 with some text and the other with the title Nyheder. Try pressing one of the news items.

edit: i am displaying the content of the post like this:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>   
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Edit: I have now discovered that when pressing one of the news post links taking me to a post page it also ruins my javascripts controlling the menu. this is very odd

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress have two types of post pages, one shows only part of the post and no comments, and the other shows everything. I don't know hoe your site is structured, but make sure that you are using that function on both pages.
For what I see, there's no logic in your code making stuff disapear...

Comment: The thing is i have a custom theme i designed myself and on the frontpage i call the_content() which also shows the content of the post selected. But when it loads that post the code that is also hardcoded into the frontpage that displays the "nyheder" sidebar just disappears